# Why type of array is this?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Okay so i'm using coinbase' API to ge the current price of BTC but when I try to use json_decode() it returns an error which is leading me to believe their responses aren't JSON.

```
https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=USD
```

That returns:

```
{"amount":"90.00","currency":"USD"}
```

I tried json_decode($grabPrice); And $grabPrice was equal to a file_get_contets() of that API. The error it gives me is:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in
```

How can I get the amount in a PHP variable?

Thanks.

Comment: What error? It's JSON as far as I can tell.

Comment: I tried json_decode($grabPrice); And $grabPrice was equal to a file_get_contets() of that API.  The error it gives me is: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Comment: that's because you where trying to print the value that is returned which in this case is an object.... `echo $returnedFromJsonDecode->amount;` instead

Comment: If you believe the response not to be JSON, run it through http://jsonlint.com before asking. If you are unsure about what json_decode returned, var_dump it before asking. If you got an error message, google it before asking.

Answer (score 2):

This is a json encoded string ....

To get the data out of it first use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
 $data = json_decode($str);

 echo $data->amount;
```

or if you prefer arrays over objects

```
 $data = json_decode($str, true);
 echo $data["amount"];
```

Comment: Here's a working demo since you beat me to the punch (bad joke): http://codepad.org/y2sXrUXf

Comment: Read my edit / comment.

Answer (score 0):

this code working fine :-

```
 $grab=file_get_contents('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=USD');
    $resarray=json_decode($grab);
echo 'amount :'.$resarray->amount.'<br>';
echo 'currency :'.$resarray->currency;
```

output :-

```
amount :89.91
currency :USD
```